# Fastest way to insert 1 million rows to realm on React Native?

Tags: react-native, realm

I know mysql and realm are different structures but,
Is there a way to quickly insert 1 million records like LOAD DATA INFILE as in mysql for realm on react native?

The api returning 1 million records and it takes 25 minutes to write schema.

My method:

```
Realm.open({ schema: [EnvanterSchema] }).then(realm => {
              realm.write(() => {
                response.data.forEach(obj => {
                  realm.create("Inventory", obj);
                });
              });

data = [{ 
    barcode: "25836693",
    Item: "Men Shoes", 
    Brand: "brand", 
    Qty: "x", 
    Size: "L"
   },....]
```

react native: 0.57.0
realm: 2.16.0

Comment: What is the use case here? Surely having 1 million records on the device is not performant at all. Why is data not served over an API?

Comment: The app will make a product checking without network.

Comment: Why not ship initial Realm data, then only sync changes from backend?